# How to convert blob into .png and send it via firebase notification?

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem when I try to send .png image via firebase service. Notification works fine and it comes to my phone, but, without image. Also, I've tried putting a direct link to the image from internet but when I tried to convert blob from database into .png and send it like that It doesnt send picture. I guess that I am not sending the image the right way?
Here is my controller code below:

Java

```
    Company company = companyService.findCompanyByName(systemUserService.findByUsername(principal.getName()).getCompany().getName());
    Notification notify = notificationService.findByName(name);

    System.out.println("Title: " + notify.getName());
    System.out.println("Message: " + notify.getText());
    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    body.put("to", "/topics/" + TOPIC);
    body.put("priority", "high");

    JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
    notification.put("title", notify.getName());
    notification.put("body", notify.getText());
    notification.put("sound", "default");

    try {
        byte[] aByteArray = company.getLogo();
        int width = 1;
        int height = 2;

        DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(aByteArray, aByteArray.length);

        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, 3 * width, 3, new int[] {0, 1, 2}, (Point)null);
        ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(ColorModel.getRGBdefault().getColorSpace(), false, true, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, true, null);

        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("image.png"));
        notification.put("image", image);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

    data.put("Key-1", "JSA Data 1");
    data.put("Key-2", "JSA Data 2");

    body.put("notification", notification);
    body.put("data", data);

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(body.toString());

    CompletableFuture<String> pushNotification = androidPushNotificationsService.send(request);
    CompletableFuture.allOf(pushNotification).join();

    try {
        String firebaseResponse = pushNotification.get();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(firebaseResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>("Push Notification ERROR!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this :

Download image from URL and convert to Base64 encoded String that can be JSONified.

```
public String jsonifyImage(String imageUrl) {
try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        Bitmap bMap =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());

        ByteArrayOutputStream oStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oStream);
        byte[] byteArr = oStream.toByteArray();
        return  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArr);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have these pictures online, users upload logos of their companies from their computers and they are converted and stored in a database as a blob. Later, I call that blob from database and I need to send picture of a company with notification, thats the main problem. I need to convert blob that I call from database into a .png/.jpg file and give it to notifications property "image"

Comment: Then you can do something like blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length()) and then encode it

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The result should be `image: "...base64 of the image file..."`.

```
byte[] aByteArray = company.getLogo();
String image = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aByteArray);
notification.put("image", image);
```

For json of course no image needs to be loaded. The blob should contain the bytes of the image (file).